# Vagrantfile setup to allow Ansible to SSH in

Tags: ssh, vagrantfile, ansible-inventory

I have a vagrantfile from a book about Ansible for Devops. The issue I have is that I can SSH into the servers but Ansible cannot. Here is my `vagrantfile`;

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # General Vagrant VM configuration
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 256
    v.linked_clone = true
 end

# Application server 1
  config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.dev"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
 end

# Application server 2
  config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.dev"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
 end

# Database server
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.dev"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
 end
end
```

And my Ansible `hosts` file;

```
# Application servers
[app]
192.168.60.4
192.168.60.5
# Database servers
[db]
192.168.60.6

# Group 'multi' with all servers
[multi:children]
app
db

# Variables that will be appliedto all servers
[multi:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

I know I can explicitly add `ansible_ssh_port=2200` etc but I'd rather have it setup in the `vagrantfile`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could try several things

1. Set the full ssh key path, in ansible config.
2. Try connect by your self, using ssh.
3. Check that 22th port opened, using telnet. If it’s closed you can try to disable firewall in VM. CentOS has it enabled by default.